# serial communication with arm microcontroller

Tags: c++, c, embedded, codeblocks, keil

I am trying to send data from the arm cortrx m4 microcontroller to pc through usb. There is a program written in C++ language in codeblocks ide. Basically the program sets the serial communication settings and read data using ReadFile function.
The problem is I am getting garbage values at the output even if the baud rate in pc proogram and microcontroller is same.

How can I solve this problem?

The pc program is shown below.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
HANDLE hComm;                          // Handle to the Serial port
char  ComPortName[] = "\\\\.\\COM51";  // Name of the Serial port to be opened,
BOOL  Status;                          // Status of the various operations
DWORD dwEventMask;                     // Event mask to trigger
char  TempChar;                        // Temperory Character
char  SerialBuffer[26];               // Buffer Containing Rxed Data
DWORD NoBytesRead;                     // Bytes read by ReadFile()
int i = 0;

printf("\n\n +==========================================+");
printf("\n |    Serial Port  Reception (Win32 API)    |");
printf("\n +==========================================+\n");
/*---------------------------------- Opening the Serial Port -----------*/

hComm = CreateFile( ComPortName,         // Name of the Port to be Opened
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, // Read/Write Access
                    0,                            // No Sharing
                    NULL,                         // No Security
                    OPEN_EXISTING,                // Open existing port only
                    0,                            // Non Overlapped I/O
                    NULL);                        // Null for Comm Devices

if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    printf("\n    Error! - Port %s can't be opened\n", ComPortName);
else
printf("\n    Port %s Opened\n ", ComPortName);


DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };               // Initializing DCB structure
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);

Status = GetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);    //retreives the current settings

if (Status == FALSE)
    printf("\n    Error! in GetCommState()");

        dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = 115200;      // Setting BaudRate = 115200
        dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;             // Setting ByteSize = 8
        dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONE5STOPBITS;    // Setting StopBits = 1
        dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;        // Setting Parity = None

Status = SetCommState(hComm, &dcbSerialParams);  //Configuring the port according to settings in DCB

        if (Status == FALSE)
            {
                printf("\n    Error! in Setting DCB Structure");
            }
        else //If Successfull display the contents of the DCB Structure
            {
                printf("\n\n    Setting DCB Structure Successfull\n");
                printf("\n       Baudrate = %ld", dcbSerialParams.BaudRate);
                printf("\n       ByteSize = %d", dcbSerialParams.ByteSize);
                printf("\n       StopBits = %d", dcbSerialParams.StopBits);
                printf("\n       Parity   = %d", dcbSerialParams.Parity);
            }

        //----------------- Setting Timeouts ----------------------------

        COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };
        timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout         = 50;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant    = 50;
        timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier  = 10;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant   = 50;
        timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

        if (SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts) == FALSE)
            printf("\n\n    Error! in Setting Time Outs");
        else
            printf("\n\n    Setting Serial Port Timeouts Successfull");

//-------------- Setting Receive Mask -------------------------------


if (!SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR))
    printf("\n\n    Error! in Setting CommMask");      // Error setting communications event mask
else
    printf("\n\n    Setting CommMask successfull");


    i = 0;
    printf("\n\n    Waiting for Data Reception");

    if (WaitCommEvent(hComm, &dwEventMask, NULL))
    {
         printf("\n\n    Characters Received\n");
         do
         {
                    if (ReadFile(hComm, &TempChar, 1, &NoBytesRead, NULL))
                    {
                        // A byte has been read; process it.
                        SerialBuffer[i] = TempChar;
                        //printf("\n%c\n", TempChar);
                        if(TempChar == 's')
                            printf("\ndone\n");
                        i++;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // An error occurred in the ReadFile call.
                        break;
                    }
                } while (NoBytesRead);
            }

int j =0;
for (j = 0; j < i-1; j++)       // j < i-1 to remove the dupliated last character
printf("%c", SerialBuffer[j]);

CloseHandle(hComm);//Closing the Serial Port
printf("\n +==========================================+\n");

}
```

Here image showing the garbage value printed when the char s is continuosly sent on the port.

[image: serial-read output]

The microcontroller code goes below.

```
#include "PLL.h"
#include "UART.h"

#define GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400253FC))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025400))
#define GPIO_PORTF_AFSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025420))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025510))
#define GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R        (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002551C))
#define GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025520))
#define GPIO_PORTF_CR_R         (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025524))
#define GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R      (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x40025528))
#define GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R       (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x4002552C))
#define SYSCTL_RCGC2_R          (*((volatile unsigned long *)0x400FE108))

unsigned long In;  // input from PF4


// time delay
void delay(int value)
{
    while(value){
    value--;}
}
//debug code
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char i;
    char string[20];          // global to assist in debugging
    unsigned long n;
    unsigned char c;
    char text[10] = "Hello!";
    unsigned long count;


    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |= 0x00000020;     // 1) F clock
    //delay = SYSCTL_RCGC2_R;           // delay   
    GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R = 0x4C4F434B;   // 2) unlock PortF PF0  
    GPIO_PORTF_CR_R = 0x1F;           // allow changes to PF4-0       
    GPIO_PORTF_AMSEL_R = 0x00;        // 3) disable analog function
    GPIO_PORTF_PCTL_R = 0x00000000;   // 4) GPIO clear bit PCTL  
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R = 0x0E;         // 5) PF4,PF0 input, PF3,PF2,PF1 output   
    GPIO_PORTF_AFSEL_R = 0x00;        // 6) no alternate function
    GPIO_PORTF_PUR_R = 0x11;          // enable pullup resistors on PF4,PF0       
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R = 0x1F;          // 7) enable digital pins PF4-PF0        


    PLL_Init();
    UART_Init();              // initialize UART


      n = 0;
      while(n < 10)
      {
          UART_OutChar('s');
          delay(10000);
          n++;
      }
}
```

Comment: First use some standard terminal program like `PuTTY` instead of your windows application, and see what kind of output you get. It will help to determine which side to debug.

Comment: What @EugeneSh. said, then if that shows the same garbage, you know it is the output from the embedded target rather then the PC code.  You then should check the bit timing and framing with an oscilloscope.  It is not apparent from the code posted where you are setting the baud rate and  framing.

Comment: at some point you may end up with "look at it with a scope", and perhaps you dont have one otherwise you would have tried that by now?   divide the problem in half as Eugene is saying.  use a known working dumb terminal program, if the problem goes away it is your host code if not then perhaps the mcu side.  cortex-m4 doesnt tell us anything relevant here as far as your chip and uart peripheral go...

Comment: I would say your baud rate is not what you think it is. First double and triple-check your register settings, then use scope.

Comment: I have used putty with the same baud rate 115200 and it worked well.

Comment: And as  @EugeneSh. said I have sent data from pc to microcontroller succesfully with the same baudrate. But the problem occurs only when microcontroller sends data.

Comment: Check `NoBytesRead` before storing data in the array. What value does it have?

Comment: @Lundin I intialized NoBytesRead to zero it does not change anything.

Comment: @Ashish That's not what I said. ReadFile writes 0 to it anyway. You need the check what value it has after the call to ReadFile.

Comment: @Lundin yes it is 1

Comment: Can we see your UART_OutChar function please? If I am understanding correctly, you are using a CDC class to connect to the PC directly with a USB cable? You're not using an FTDI type interface?

Comment: `void UART_OutChar(unsigned char data)                                               {                                                      while((UART0_FR_R&UART_FR_TXFF) != 0);                              UART0_DR_R = data;
}`

Comment: Thank you all for your time. By the way the problem was with the stop bits. I made it zero and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

```
UART_OutChar('s');
delay(10000);
```

This code is not correct. I suspect you keep overwriting the UART tx buffer over and over, long before the UART is given a chance to send anything at all.

First of all, you can't write the delay function like that. The compiler is free to optimize it all away, as it can't spot any side-effects. Generally, you should away "burn-away time" loops as poor man's delays, but if you for some reason must use them, they have to be written like this:

```
void delay(int value)
{
  for(volatile int i=0; i<value; i++)
  {}
}
```

The volatile keyword prevents the compiler from optimizing away the whole function.

The correct way to do this though, is not to use such blunt delays at all, but instead watch the transmitter busy flag of your UART hardware. It is found in the UART status register, whatever that one is called for your specific microcontroller.

Pseudo code:

```
n = 0;
while(n < 10)
{
  if((UART_SR & TX_BUSY) == 0)
  {
    UART_OutChar('s');
    n++;
  }

  /* can do other things here in the meantime */
}
```

Comment: after the changes you suggested i am getting same error.