# Calling from one function to other functions within the same C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to call other adjacent functions (`delay()` and `delay_ex()`) from a function (`bitcheck()`) as shown below and as expected, the compiler has thrown an error that `delay()` and `delay_ex()` functions weren't declared in the scope and I understood that we can't call functions other than from the `main`. So, I declared these `delay()` and `delay_ex()` functions in a header file and called from this program by including the header file, it worked well. So, is there any other such way to make this work?

```
void bitcheck()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NELEMS(array); i++)
    {       
        delay();
        AP_CMU->DIVIDER = freq_def[0];
        encryption(array,i);
        delay();
        // LCD_DisplayUint32(i,0,array[i]);
        AP_CMU->DIVIDER = freq_def[6];
        delay_ex(10);
        decryption(intr_array,i);
        delay_ex(10);
        // LCD_DisplayUint32(i,10,array[i]);
    }

}

void delay()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        __NOP();
    }
}

void delay_ex(int j)
{
    for(int s=0; s < j; s++)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            __NOP();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `I understood that we can't call functions other than from the main`..nopes.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Your delay code is probably broken. Are you sure that the compiler won't optimize away NOP instructions? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880938/serial-communication-with-arm-microcontroller/41895798#41895798).

Comment: @Lundin: If it does, it is broken (or the intrinsic is wrongly declared).

Comment: @Olaf That is, assuming that `__NOP()` expands to `asm NOP` or similar. If it is an empty function, it will obviously get optimized away.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, that's the assumption, applying Occam's Razor. Anything else would fall int the "broken" cathegory.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your functions above the code that calls them like:

```
void foo() {
}

void bar() {
}
int main () {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

You can also forward declare functions like:

```
void foo();
void bar();
int main () {
    foo();
    bar();
}
void foo() {
}

void bar() {
}
```

Or you can put them in a header file and include it

file.h:

```
void foo();
void bar();
```

file.c:

```
#include "file.h"
int main () {
    foo();
    bar();
}
void foo() {
}

void bar() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler works in a single pass, as such when `bitcheck()` is parsed, the signatures of `delay()` and `delay_ex()` are not known, so the compiler cannot verify the call is type-correct.

The rule is *declare or define before use*; there are two possible solutions:

- Define `bitcheck()` *after* the definition of `delay()` and `delay_ex()`
- Forward-declare `delay()` and `delay_ex()`.

By declaring the functions in a header and including it *before* defining `bitcheck()`, you used the second of these solutions, but use of an include file was not essential - `#include` does noting more than insert the file content into the translation-unit prior to compilation.  This is useful when the symbols will be called from a different translation-unit than that in which they are defined; if that is not intended the declarations may be written directly rather then `#include`'d, and should also be declared `static` to avoid external-linkage and potential name clashes with other translation-units.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define delay and delay_ex before bitcheck. Simply moving those two functions above bitcheck should suffice.